Store data from index.html on WebView Android
I have this Android App Project with a WebviewActivity.kt file that calls an index.html which has a script like this to save a string on storage:
<script>
            function saveData(){
                var text = document.getElementByld('content').value;
                window.dataStorage.save(text);
                document.getElementByld('lastText').innerHTML = 'Saved value: ' + text
            ｝
</script>

The index.html is working fine and have all these elements from above, my questions is what should I do in my .kt file in order to make window.dataStorage.save(text) work? I think it has something to do with creating a Context.dataStore variable on a DataStoreManager class and maybe adding webView.addJavascriptInterface(DataStoreManager(this), "window") to my webview variable? I really don't understand much.
